# Does a Bangladeshi need a visa for Northern Ireland?

Tags: bangladeshi-citizens, northern-ireland, danish-residents

I hold Bangladeshi national Passport. But I have Permanent residence permit in Denmark. Should I need Visa for visit in  Northern Ireland?

Answer (score 10):

You will need a visa to visit Northern Ireland. You can verify this at the UK government website: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Note that the UK, including Northern Ireland, is not part of the Schengen area and your Denmark residency is not relevant.

Comment: You will also need a separate visa for Ireland if you cross the border into the Republic of Ireland... I know OP doesn't state that, but it's sometimes easily done.

Comment: Agreed. If you get stopped by the gardai and don't have a visa for the republic, they'll stick you on a flight and deport you back home. You don't get sent back up north. This happened to a colleague of mine who'd only gone down south on a day trip and had a hell of an ordeal, as well as having to pay for a flight back to the UK.

Comment: You'll definatily get away with it if your driving, but there are regular checks for bus and train services. But just get yourself the visa